# Calculate the difference between two time strings "07:35 AM" and "09:35 PM" in hours

Tags: ios, swift, date

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkad3.png)I am having the times on two button on its title I am having the two time with AM/PM.
I have tried so many ways to subtract the times between these two buttons but not successful.
Please suggest me the proper way as the how to subtract the IN time and OUT time and get the TOTAL HOUR as a result only in hours.

Comment: What's stopping you from using the search box at the top-right corner?

Comment: @ElTomato Sir I tried but not found the satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Calendar method dateComponents to calculate how many hours there is between two dates. You can use DateFormatter to get the dates from your strings:

```
let start = "09:35 PM"
let end = "09:36 AM"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

if let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start),
    let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: end) {
    let hours = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: startDate, to: endDate < startDate ? Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: endDate) ?? endDate : endDate).hour ?? 0
    print(hours)  // 12
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question, I need one more help could you please suggest the to find the difference in minutes too.

Comment: `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: startDate, to: endDate).minute`

Comment: sir lets suppose:  let start = "21:35 PM"
let end = "09:36 AM" the answer is not coming proper, as we need the answer in this format 13:01

Comment: @raj You can check if the end date is earlier than start date just add a day to it.

Comment: Thanks sir for your precious help, but I performed the task in a long way. I am posting the code please have a look. actually as I am a newbie so its difficult for me to understand with instructions. Thanks sir.

Comment: Thanks Hero!! Worked for me in 5 Sec.

Answer (score -1):

Convert both time into `Date` object and then just use below statement.

```
let interval = laterDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(earlierDate)
```

Hope this will help you...