# iOS Swift - Calculate the difference between two times

Tags: ios, swift, time

I would like to know how to calculate the difference between the login time and log out time, for Example: Login time: 8:00 AM and Logout time: 5:00 PM, and I should get 9 hours as total hours rendered.

This is the format of the time that is saved to Firebase

```
     // Set the time
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateStyle = .none
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    timeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    timeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

    let timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 2 dates in weeks and days using swift 3 and xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294864/difference-between-2-dates-in-weeks-and-days-using-swift-3-and-xcode-8)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017851/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, sorry for that. Thanks for the reminders. Have a great day!

Comment: @LeoDabus, I tried the solution you posted on that post and it is what I needed. I should have looked further and could have found your post before asking this question. Thank you so much! Again, I apologize for asking this question.

Comment: @TSM you are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find difference in seconds between NSDates as integer using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599172/find-difference-in-seconds-between-nsdates-as-integer-using-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At login...

```
    let loginTime = Date()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(loginTime, forKey: "loginTime")
```

Then at logout...

```
    let loginTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "loginTime") as? Date ?? Date()
    let loginInterval = -loginTime.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = false
    formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = false
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]

    // Use the configured formatter to generate the string.
    let userLoginTimeString = formatter.string(from: loginInterval) ?? ""
    print("user was logged in for \(userLoginTimeString)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ekscrypto. I will try this out too. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 6):

*Edit:* [Found duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294864/difference-between-2-dates-in-weeks-and-days-using-swift-3-and-xcode-8)

Create `Date` objects ([link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861732/swift-convert-string-to-date)) from the login (`loginTime`) and logout (`logoutTime`) times, and then use them like so:

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: loginTime, to: logoutTime)

// To get the hours
print(components.hour)
// To get the minutes
print(components.minute)
```

Comment: @aksh1t   I am using this but  [.hour, .minute] getting error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" How can I resolve it.

Comment: @ekscrypto can you please tell me . why I am getting this error.

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh this isn't my code or answer.  Check my answer for proper syntax/usage