# Swift How can i get difference between time 02:00 PM and 01:00 AM

Tags: ios, swift

Swift How can i get difference between time 02:00 PM and 01:00 AM

```
            `let timeSlot1 = "01:00 AM"
             let timeSlot2 = "08:30 PM"
            //Want difference between both
            //and result value into an Integer formate`
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017206/calculate-the-difference-between-two-time-strings-0735-am-and-0935-pm-in-h

Comment: No its not working , when i enter the time 01:00 AM and 11:30 PM i am getting 22 hrs difference instead of 22.30 hrs

Comment: The duplicate is about hours. You have to specify `.hour` and `.minute` components.

Comment: Oh thanks ...i changed formate .minute and its working fine........i am getting difference into minute which is also my solution